# Spring security predefined implementation for roles creation dynamically and access to urls dynmically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Does spring providing any inbuilt implementation for creating roles dynamically and giving permissions to urls dynamically

My requirement is client will create roles based on his choice  like staffbatch1, staffbatch2 and he want to give few url access to batch1 and few urls to batch2 and , it's spring mvc application using jsp , urls nothing but tabs in dashboard

Comment: You can come up a filter, place it after spring's default authority check filter, and do you work there.

Comment: so default filter will first filter ? i am bit confused, current implementation  it will check the current user is authenticated or not by getting details from database ,a predefined spring security implementation. need to change that

Comment: I am considering that a few of such roles would be fixed in your application. For that, you can use spring's default implementation. And for the dynamic ones, you create a filter, that always retrieves latest details for a url and for logged in person and does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: just admin is fixed but other roles it should be dynamic , like suppose i want to create a role for contract employee to access just one tab in my dashboard that will show some data like that